# angular form data to json object

Tags: json, angular, forms

I am having an angular form, on submit i am getting data in below format

```
permission[0].id: "284"
permission[0].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[1].id: "230"
permission[1].isNotReasignable: ""
permission[2].id: "75"
permission[2].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[3].id: "169"
permission[3].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[4].id: "73"
permission[4].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[5].id: "76"
permission[5].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[6].id: "229"
permission[6].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[7].id: "71"
permission[7].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[8].id: "77"
permission[8].isNotReasignable: "1"
permission[9].id: "145"
permission[9].isNotReasignable: "1"
```

but i want it in below format before i submit it to API

```
permission: Array(10)
0: {id: "284", isNotReasignable: "1"}
1: {id: "230"}
2: {id: "75", isNotReasignable: "1"}
3: {id: "169", isNotReasignable: "1"}
4: {id: "73", isNotReasignable: "1"}
5: {id: "76", isNotReasignable: "1"}
6: {id: "229", isNotReasignable: "1"}
7: {id: "71", isNotReasignable: "1"}
8: {id: "77", isNotReasignable: "1"}
9: {id: "145", isNotReasignable: "1"}
```

really appreciate your response, thanks

Comment: you are getting it in `var permission = [{id: "284",isNotReasignable: "1"}, {id: "230",isNotReasignable: ""}]` this format ?

Comment: @muthukumarhelius, yes i want this in the format you mentioned. thanks

Comment: previously how are getting ? mention the format like this `var permission = [{id: "284",isNotReasignable: "1"}]` and edit your question with the format are you getting it as object